# HSL Colours with ThreeJs

Tags: javascript, colors, three.js, hsl

Having a bit of trouble getting HSL colours to work with ThreeJs. Here's my code:

```
var exampleColor = new THREE.Color( 0xffffff );
exampleColor.setHSL( getHSLColour(exampleObject) );
var exampleMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial ( {color: exampleColor} );
```

The output of getHSLColour is something like:

```
0.06721230158730158, 0.9913555194805196, 0.658271103896104
```

Which seems to match the format ThreeJs wants. But when I print exampleColor to the console, it still shows up as an RGB colour with NaN values:

```
T…E.Color {r: NaN, g: NaN, b: NaN}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

`setHSL` expects three different parameters, not an array:

```
var hsl = getHSLColour(exampleObject);
exampleColor.setHSL( hsl[0], hsl[1], hsl[2] );
```